# Has Apple said anything about depreciating xib in favor of storyboards?

Tags: ios, xib, xcode-storyboard

At my company, we're trying to evaluate between using storyboards (the more recent Apple supported tool) and xib files (the older tool). Technical differences aside, a concern that has popped up, is that since Apple appears to be pushing for using storyboards in new development, they will drop support for xib files in the future.

At this time (January 2014), is this a valid concern for iOS development?

To avoid this from becoming an opinion-based question, let me also ask - has there been any official indication from Apple on the matter?

Apple usually gives a notice period before they drop support for something, so if they haven't said anything, I guess it's reasonable to conclude that they will continue to support the xib approach.

Comment: Storyboard is just a group of XIB.

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually opinion-based, since this merely asking if Apple has given any statements about it, which is pretty objective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Apple has not officially stated anything when it comes to deprecating XIBs in favor of storyboards. Chances are both will remain for the time being, as they're both useful (sometimes you don't really want or need a storyboard and a standalone XIB will suffice). Anything beyond that would be speculation that seems better left to bloggers.

Comment: Thanks. At least, that settles my worry if Apple said something and I missed it.